# can't return value/variable in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

when I console.log it display all the arrays to be the string, because in my arrays, they are multi-dimensions; look below the code using console.log in function, without return but undefined

```js
function changeStrings(arr, replacement) {
    var newArr = []

  for ( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    newArr.push(arr[i].split(" "))
  }

  for ( var j = 0 ; j < replacement.length ; j++ ) {
    newArr[0][3] = replacement[j-2]
    newArr[1][3] = replacement[j-1]
    newArr[2][4] = replacement[j]
  }
   
  for ( var k = 0 ; k < newArr.length ; k++ ) {
    console.log(newArr[k].join(" "))
  }
 
};


let initial = ["my city in London", "my name is Mike", "my phone number is 00909090"];
let replacements = ['Paris', 'John', '1234'];

console.log(changeStrings(initial, replacements))
```

and if i using return , it just print one line;

check this

```js
function changeStrings(arr, replacement) {
    var newArr = []

  for ( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    newArr.push(arr[i].split(" "))
  }

  for ( var j = 0 ; j < replacement.length ; j++ ) {
    newArr[0][3] = replacement[j-2]
    newArr[1][3] = replacement[j-1]
    newArr[2][4] = replacement[j]
  }
   
  for ( var k = 0 ; k < newArr.length ; k++ ) {
    var dispplay = newArr[k].join(" ")
    return dispplay
  }
 
};

// now let's test out our functions!
let initial = ["my city in London", "my name is Mike", "my phone number is 00909090"];
let replacements = ['Paris', 'John', '1234'];

console.log(changeStrings(initial, replacements))
```

the newArr variable is array multidimension 
it looks like this ;

```
[ [ 'my', 'city', 'in', 'Paris' ],
  [ 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John' ],
  [ 'my', 'phone', 'number', 'is', '1234' ] ]
```

i am trying to  using for loop for this case, because i want to train my logic;), can anyone help me to find out what's wrong ? or fix this ? 
thank you

Comment: The problem is that `return`statement end the whole loop (same as 'break'). You can not return directly like that.

Answer (score 1):

The function is returning just after the first iteration of the loop. That prevents the rest of the iterations from execution. You have to return an array from the function. You can `push()` all the item to the array inside the loop then return the array:

```js
function changeStrings(arr, replacement) {
  var newArr = []

  for ( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    newArr.push(arr[i].split(" "))
  }

  for ( var j = 0 ; j < replacement.length ; j++ ) {
    newArr[0][3] = replacement[j-2]
    newArr[1][3] = replacement[j-1]
    newArr[2][4] = replacement[j]
  }
  var display = [];
  for ( var k = 0 ; k < newArr.length ; k++ ) {
    display.push(newArr[k].join(" "));
  }
 
  return display
};

// now let's test out our functions!
let initial = ["my city in London", "my name is Mike", "my phone number is 00909090"];
let replacements = ['Paris', 'John', '1234'];

console.log(changeStrings(initial, replacements))
```

Comment: so we should loop again to print those arrays? :D @Mamun

Comment: @ZrClassic, yes, since the returned result is an array, you have to loop to print those.....thanks

Comment: @ZrClassic, you can also join the array to return string like `return display.join('.....')` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `return` statement end the whole loop immediately (same as `break`) . You can not return directly like that, if you want to finish the loop. On the other way, you can use it purposefuly to end the loop, for instance if you found a desired item and don't neet to loop anymore.

How to actually use return in loop:

```
let fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'strawbery'];
let myFavoriteFruit === 'orange';

const IncludesMyFavouriteFruit = (list) => {
    for (let item of list) {
        if (item === myFavoriteFruit) return true;  // Ends the loop; we'll never get to 'pear' and 'strawbery'.
    }
    return false; // There is not my favourite fruit.
}
```

Sorry for using ES6, too lazy to write old JS.

Comment: can u give example